# Interaction with contrast and dummy coding

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, contrasts

I have a question regarding the interpretation of an interaction using categorical variables where one is dummy coded (0, 1) and the other is contrast coded.

The variables are:

- Var1: 3 levels, coded using planned orthogonal contrasts (level 1 vs. level 2+3, and level 2 vs. level 3)
- Var2: 2 levels, dummy coded

The results from a logit mixed model regression using R and Lme4 gives the following general results:

```
Var11       n.s.    
Var12       n.s.
Var2        ***
Var11:Var2  ***
Var12:Var2  n.s
```

Now, as I understand it, the main effects are in fact simple effects and gives the result for the contrasts in Var1 on the first (0) level of Var2 only ([link](http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/tvw/catpred/)). But how do I interpret the interaction? Is it a "simple interaction" as well, and how should that be interpreted? How would this differ from an analysis where Var2 is coded in another way (say -1, 1)?